# dynamic training/test classes with ML.NET

Tags: c#, machine-learning, ml.net

This is a follow up from the question here
[Dynamic classes/objects ML.net's PredictionMoadel<TInput, TOutput> Train()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51486833/dynamic-classes-objects-ml-nets-predictionmoadeltinput-toutput-train/51898488?noredirect=1#comment92464548_51898488)

My system cannot use a predefined class at compile time, therefore I tried to feed a dynamic class into ML.NET like below

```
    // field data type
    public class Field
    {
        public string FieldName { get; set; }
        public Type FieldType { get; set; }
    }

    // dynamic class helper
    public class DynamicClass : DynamicObject
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<Type, object>> _fields;

        public DynamicClass(List<Field> fields)
        {
            _fields = new Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<Type, object>>();
            fields.ForEach(x => _fields.Add(x.FieldName,
                new KeyValuePair<Type, object>(x.FieldType, null)));
        }

        public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
        {
            if (_fields.ContainsKey(binder.Name))
            {
                var type = _fields[binder.Name].Key;
                if (value.GetType() == type)
                {
                    _fields[binder.Name] = new KeyValuePair<Type, object>(type, value);
                    return true;
                }
                else throw new Exception("Value " + value + " is not of type " + type.Name);
            }
            return false;
        }

        public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
        {
            result = _fields[binder.Name].Value;
            return true;
        }
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var fields = new List<Field>
        {
            new Field {FieldName = "Name", FieldType = typeof(string)},
            new Field {FieldName = "Income", FieldType = typeof(float)}
        };

        dynamic obj1 = new DynamicClass(fields);
        obj1.Name = "John";
        obj1.Income = 100f;

        dynamic obj2 = new DynamicClass(fields);
        obj2.Name = "Alice";
        obj2.Income = 200f;

        var trainingData = new List<dynamic> {obj1, obj2};

        var env = new LocalEnvironment();
        var schemaDef = SchemaDefinition.Create(typeof(DynamicClass));
        schemaDef.Add(new SchemaDefinition.Column(null, "Name", TextType.Instance));
        schemaDef.Add(new SchemaDefinition.Column(null, "Income", NumberType.R4));
        var trainDataView = env.CreateStreamingDataView(trainingData, schemaDef);

        var pipeline = new CategoricalEstimator(env, "Name")
            .Append(new ConcatEstimator(env, "Features", "Name"))
            .Append(new FastTreeRegressionTrainer(env, "Income", "Features"));

        var model = pipeline.Fit(trainDataView);
    }
```

and got the error: "'No field or property with name 'Name' found in type 'System.Object'". I tried generating the class using Reflection only to run into the same problem.

Is there a workaround? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using ExpandoObject? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530134/is-it-possible-to-add-attributes-to-a-property-of-dynamic-object-runtime

Comment: I was not aware of ExpandoObject, good to know, thanks

Comment: I have a complete example of how to do this using a runtime generated class: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66913705/125406

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic class doesn't actually create a class definition but it rather provides you with dynamic object.

I looked at the code for `SchemaDefinition.Create()` it needs an actual class definition to build the schema. So your options are to create and load a class definition dynamically.

You can create your class as string with all dynamic properties and compile it using Microsoft compiler services aka `Roslyn`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32769630/how-to-compile-a-c-sharp-file-with-roslyn-programmatically/32770961#32770961). This will generate an assembly (in memory as memory stream or on file system) with your dynamic type.

Now you are only half way there. To get your dynamic type from dynamic assembly you need to load it in the App Domain. See [this](https://www.cshandler.com/2014/09/appdomain-and-dynamic-assemblies.html) post. 
Once the assembly is loaded you can use '[Activator.CreateInstance()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=netframework-4.7.2)' if it's same domain or if it's your custom domain then you would need `yourDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap()` to create the object out of dynamically generated Class and to get the type use `Assembly.GetType()`.

Few sample here, A little out of date but will get you on your feet if you are up for this. See [CompilerEngine](https://github.com/vendettamit/CodeRank/blob/master/src/CodeRank/CompilerEngine.cs) and [CompilerService](https://github.com/vendettamit/CodeRank/blob/master/src/CodeRank.Api.Service/CompilerService.cs) to compile and load the assembly.

**Other options**: `Refelection.Emit()` but it requires a great deal of IL level coding. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3862241/881798).

Comment: I did try the reflection solution, that didn't help, will check out others then

Answer (score 7):

For those attempting to do this, I have a working solution that creates the schema and can be used to train data dynamically.

First, grab the code for DynamicTypeProperty and DynamicType from my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55738461/5369726).

The following code will create a schema dynamically:

```
var properties = new List<DynamicTypeProperty>()
{
    new DynamicTypeProperty("SepalLength", typeof(float)),
    new DynamicTypeProperty("SepalWidth", typeof(float)),
    new DynamicTypeProperty("PetalLength", typeof(float)),
    new DynamicTypeProperty("PetalWidth", typeof(float)),
};

// create the new type
var dynamicType = DynamicType.CreateDynamicType(properties);
var schema = SchemaDefinition.Create(dynamicType);
```

You'll then need to create list with the required data.  This is done as follows:

```
var dynamicList = DynamicType.CreateDynamicList(dynamicType);

// get an action that will add to the list
var addAction = DynamicType.GetAddAction(dynamicList);

// call the action, with an object[] containing parameters in exact order added
addAction.Invoke(new object[] {1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4});
// call add action again for each row.
```

Then you'll need to create an IDataView with the data, this requires using reflection, or the trainers won't infer the correct type.

```
            var mlContext = new MLContext();
            var dataType = mlContext.Data.GetType();
            var loadMethodGeneric = dataType.GetMethods().First(method => method.Name =="LoadFromEnumerable" && method.IsGenericMethod);
            var loadMethod = loadMethodGeneric.MakeGenericMethod(dynamicType);
            var trainData = (IDataView) loadMethod.Invoke(mlContext.Data, new[] {dynamicList, schema});
```

You then, should be able to run the `trainData` through your pipeline.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Gary! I was able to create a dynamic IDataView from your example. However, I have a follow up question. Once you train a model, you have to create a Prediction Engine which asks for the source class type to be declared. However, I'm unsure how to declare this class since the I'm using a static instance of a dynamic type. Am I misunderstanding how to use these classes? Or can you provide a brief example of how you might use the IDataView created in this example to instantiate a Prediction Engine?

Comment: @andyopayne, take a look at my answer to another similar question.  I posted some sample code to do exactly this.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66893993/ml-net-create-prediction-engine-using-dynamic-class/66913705#66913705

Answer (score 0):

Right now I'm using a dummy place holder like this as a workaround

```
    public class TrainingSample
    {
        public string TextField1;
        public string TextField2;
        public string TextField3;
        public string TextField4;
        public string TextField5;

        public float FloatField1;
        public float FloatField2;
        public float FloatField3;
        public float FloatField4;
        public float FloatField5;
        public float FloatField6;
        public float FloatField7;
        public float FloatField8;
        public float FloatField9;
        public float FloatField10;
        public float FloatField11;
        public float FloatField12;
        public float FloatField13;
        public float FloatField14;
        public float FloatField15;
    }
```

Comment: You could instead have a vector of FloatFeatures and Vector of TextFeatures and then just use encoding estimator steps that accept vector arguments.  Most of the numeric ones accept vectors for the input column and for text features there are a few (e.g. ApplyWordEmbedding) 
ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.transforms.text?view=ml-dotnet

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty old but I was trying to do this for a long time, I wanted to be able to feed any kind of data into an existing quant strategy and train different models from that data by just passing an enum for which model to train and what data type to use, so that i dont need to rewrite everything or have thousands of lines of code just to train a model from a new data set.
the first part was solved by a simple switch statement, but having inherited types as a data source was a real problem.

I found a way to use inherited classes in the pipeline. the original problem was that the pipeline would only recognise the base class or the interface properties. casting etc just didnt work even if I knew the type before compile time. the trick was to make the predict method reflective or dynamic (i don't know the language to use for this), I don't really have the explanation. this is the test program i made to solve the problem. In my test I call the data Food, each type of food inherits baseFood and that in turn inherits IFood.

The object calling the method still needs to know what type of food it uses, but it can pass in any type of concrete class that inherits either IFood or BaseFood, depending how you write it.

you can still save the prediction engine by saving as a generic object.

to manage all the types and their engines, context, model and food, i use dictionaries where the key is a type, that type is the concrete food type.
so each time a new data set, context or model is created, the new type can be added to the dictionary.

the test demo also has a method for training from serialised data, but no example, it can be used in a while loop to keep training a pipeline from serialised data until the method returns an empty list. included this bit for anyone else who wanted to know it because i found it useful and I am new to ML.

excuse my unprofessional language, I only really know what i need to know for my own personal trading purposes :)

https://github.com/BurnOutTrader/DynamicMLPipeline
the link contains a wroking example of dynamic schema factory, training from inherited types as well as training and predicting.

```
private static void DynamicPredict(MLContext context, Type type, List<IFood> testFoods)
    {
        var model = Model[type];
        var foodType = type; // Concrete type derived from IFood

        //The real trick is this combined with the schema factory
        // Get the CreatePredictionEngine method info with specific parameter types
        MethodInfo createEngineMethod = context.Model.GetType().GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Single(m => m.Name == "CreatePredictionEngine" 
                         && m.GetParameters().Length == 4 // Assuming the method has 4 parameters
                         && m.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType == typeof(ITransformer)
                         && m.GetParameters()[1].ParameterType == typeof(bool)
                         && m.GetParameters()[2].ParameterType == typeof(SchemaDefinition)
                         && m.GetParameters()[3].ParameterType == typeof(SchemaDefinition))
            .MakeGenericMethod(foodType, typeof(BinaryClassification)); // Assuming BinaryClassification is your output class

        
        if (!PredictionEngine.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            //dynamically create the prediction engine and save it as a generic object to the dictionary, by the type of food it consumes.(key)
            var predictionEngine = createEngineMethod.Invoke(context.Model, new object[] { model, false, null, null });
            PredictionEngine.Add(type, predictionEngine);
        }
        
        // Get the method info for the Predict function of the prediction engine
        MethodInfo predictMethod = PredictionEngine[foodType].GetType().GetMethod("Predict", new[] { foodType });
        
        
        // Make predictions on each food item
        foreach (var food in testFoods.Take(2))
        {
            // Predict dynamically
            var prediction = predictMethod.Invoke(PredictionEngine[foodType], new[] { food });
            
            Console.WriteLine($"Prediction for {foodType.Name}: {(prediction as BinaryClassification).PredictedLabel}");
        }
    }
```