# Make Method Generic from Dynamic Type

Tags: c#

I have a method that currently creates a dynamic type at run time. The method is largely [taken from this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55738567/1394922). The code works as is and create the type just fine. However, later in the code I need to use this type as a generic. This is where I'm a bit stuck. The part where the generic type is used is here:

```
mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<TSrc,TDst>(ITransformer, DataViewSchema)
```

where the ***TDst*** is known prior to compile time, but ***TSrc*** is not. TSrc in this is example is my dynamic type which is created in this method:

```
public static Type CreateDynamicType(IEnumerable<DynamicTypeProperty> properties)
{
    StringBuilder classCode = new StringBuilder();

    // Generate the class code
    classCode.AppendLine("using System;");
    classCode.AppendLine("namespace Dexih {");
    classCode.AppendLine("public class DynamicClass {");

    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        classCode.AppendLine($"public {property.Type.Name} {property.Name} {{get; set; }}");
    }
    classCode.AppendLine("}");
    classCode.AppendLine("}");

    var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(classCode.ToString());

    var references = new MetadataReference[]
    {
        MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location),
        MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(DictionaryBase).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location)
    };

    var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("DynamicClass" + Guid.NewGuid() + ".dll",
        syntaxTrees: new[] { syntaxTree },
        references: references,
        options: new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary));

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var result = compilation.Emit(ms);

        if (!result.Success)
        {
            var failures = result.Diagnostics.Where(diagnostic =>
                diagnostic.IsWarningAsError ||
                diagnostic.Severity == DiagnosticSeverity.Error);

            var message = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var diagnostic in failures)
            {
                message.AppendFormat("{0}: {1}", diagnostic.Id, diagnostic.GetMessage());
            }

            throw new Exception($"Invalid property definition: {message}.");
        }
        else
        {

            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var assembly = Assembly.Load(ms.ToArray());
            var dynamicType = assembly.GetType("Dexih.DynamicClass");                  
            return dynamicType;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone describe how to modify the ***CreateDynamicType*** method so that it can return a generic type which can be used in the ***CreatePredictionEngine*** function?

**EDIT (based on Kit's answer)**

At the very bottom, I create an instance of the prediction engine by invoking the generic method. However, that simply returns a generic object type. I need to be able to then call *engine.Predict(args)* to be able to actually make a prediction using the engine ([see docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.predictionenginebase-2.predict?view=ml-dotnet#Microsoft_ML_PredictionEngineBase_2_Predict__0_)). I tried casting the return object to a *PredictionEngine* type, but that didn't seem to work. Do I have to create a new generic method for the *Predict* method too?

```
var dynamicType = DynamicType.CreateDynamicType(properties);
var inputSchema = SchemaDefinition.Create(dynamicType);
var outputSchema = SchemaDefinition.Create(typeof(ModelOutput));

var dataType = mlContext.Model.GetType();
var createEngineGeneric = dataType.GetMethods().First(method => method.Name == "CreatePredictionEngine" && method.IsGenericMethod);

var genericMethod = createEngineGeneric.MakeGenericMethod(dynamicType, typeof(ModelOutput));
object[] args = new object[]{ model , true, inputSchema, outputSchema };
var engine = genericMethod.Invoke(mlContext.Model, args);
```

Comment: ".. type which can be used in the CreatePredictionEngine function?" Unless '`CreatePredictionEngine` has a type constraint on `TSrc`, *any* type can be used with it, so your question doesn't make any sense. Are you asking how to invoke `CreatePredictionEngine` with the type you just created? See [How to use reflection to invoke a generic method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/232621/2791540).

Comment: Thanks @JohnWu. The `TSrc` is actually asking for the class object which defines the input for the prediction engine... which in this case, should be the dynamic type that is returned in the `CreateDynamicType`. So, I can create an instance of this type by calling `var dynamicType = DynamicType.CreateDynamicType(properties);` but then I am unable to use `dynamicType` as the generic `TSrc` since it says it is a variable and can't be used as a type. I guess I'm just very confused as to how I can define `TSrc` from a dynamic class object created after run time.

Comment: You need to call `CreatePredictionEngine` dynamically also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to modify the method at all. What you need to do is take the `Type` returned and use that to create a generic method using [MakeGenericMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod?view=net-5.0) that you can then invoke.

```
var dynamicType = DynamicType.CreateDynamicType(properties);
var method = mlContext.Model.GetType().GetMethod("CreatePredictionEngine");
System.Type type2 = ...; // however/wherever you get this instance of Type from
var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(dynamicType, type2);
var param1 = ...; // however/wherever this comes from
var param2 = ...; // however/wherever this comes from

generic.Invoke(mlContext.Model, param1, param2);
```

That the type is generated dynamically by your `CreateDynamicType` method is not relevant. You can use any instance of System.Type from any source as the instance on which you call `MakeGenericMethod`.

Now to actually use your engine, assign it to a `dynamic`. This allows you to dynamically call the `Predict` method.

```
dynamic engine = (dynamic)genericMethod.Invoke(mlContext.Model, args);
var dest = engine.Predict(source)
```

Alternatively, you're right, you could create another generic method for `Predict` and invoke that with reflection.

Without knowing the rest of your code, you'll have to continue dynamic calls using `dest` until you're done with it, unless you can get back to a point where you can then call normal type safe C#.